# Are there any HTML element attributes used to provide information about dynamic content

Tags: html, dynamic, seo, ria

I remember reading an article about a specific set of attributes that could be used to describe the content, type, update frequency etc of elements with dynamic data in them.

The whole idea behind it, was to specify the sections of your Web Applications that have dynamic data in them and provide bots/crawlers with more information.

Just to get the concept, here's a sample code (***the attributes i will be using are of course made up***)

```
<div id="username" dataType="string" updateFrequency="rarely">Theo</div>
<div id="score" dataType="integer" updateFrequency="daily">9001</div>
```

I know this is really vague. Perhaps someone out there knows what I am talking about

Thanks for any help

Comment: The [aria-live](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-live) property indicates to a screenreader that an area of the page should be read out when it is updated, whether because specific values change as in your example, or because new content appears, as might be the case in a chat window. But as the answer below mentions, it's exclusively for screenreaders, not used by SEO. (Also note that current screenreaders do not yet implement it exactly as spec'd, not all attribute values are supported.)

Comment: It seems i was wrong thinking that this had to do something with ARIA. I'm only trying to remember what I read in that article. It could have been just a concept. I'm only hoping its not

Comment: @Dogoku: Maybe what you read was about setting the update frequency for pages, not for elements? If so, http://www.sitemaps.org/ might be what you are looking for.

Comment: No, I am already familiar with that. The article was referring to attributes placed directly on elements to describe their data. I remember that much. Now if only I could remember where I read it...

Answer (score 0):

[ARIA](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/) (Accessible Rich Internet Applications) attributes are for improving accessibility, not for search engines. They can be used to describe the roles of elements, e.g. saying that a `div` element is really a progress bar or that a `span` is for decoration only.

Invented attributes will generally be ignored by all software. According to HTML5 drafts, and in practice, you can use `data-`* attributes to associate any invisible data with elements, but they are by definition application-specific and ignored by search engines.

Search engines are generally not interested in the update rates of individual elements. They analyze the update rates of *pages* on the basis of their own observations.

There are ways to associate, in markup, metadata with specific elements, in a manner that may be observed by major search engines; see [Schema.org](http://schema.org/). But in practice, such markup seems to have impact on search engines only for pages in a major commercial or community sites. For Joe Q. Author’s pages, they are probably write-only information (for now).